# Number mhchem reactions and create a \listofreactions

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering, environments, mhchem

Is there a way to create an environment for reactions defined with mhchem  that behaves similarly to equation in terms of numbering the reactions (including a \nonumber command)? Can I get a list of those reactions?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}

\newcounter{rxnum}

\newenvironment{reaction}{
\refstepcounter{rxnum}
\noindent
%???
}{
%???
\par\noindent
}

\begin{document}

\begin{reaction}
 \ce{X + Y -> XY}
\end{reaction}

\begin{reaction}
 \ce{XX + YY -> X2Y2} \\%<- newline just like in equation
 \ce{A + B -> C}
\end{reaction}  


\end{document}
```

This is a two part question. The first part is about creating an environment that behaves similarly to equation, but for reactions defined in mhchem. I had a look in source2e in the definition of equation (around l. 293 in source2e) but couldn't quite figure out how to transfer that onto my new environment.

The second part is about how to create a list of those reactions containing the reaction number, the page they occur on and optional a description that is only printed in the \listofreactions.

For example:

In the code I write

```
\begin{reaction}
\ce{X + Y ->XY}\descriptionforlist{XY formation reaction}\\
\ce{A +B -> C}
\ce{G + H -> J}\nonumber
    \end{reaction}
```

Then in the list it should appear as

**List of reaction**

```
R 1: XY formation reaction                6

R 2:                                      6
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/chemmacros) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  modules = {reactions} ,
  formula = mhchem
}
\begin{document}

\listofreactions

\begin{reaction}[bla]
 $A$ ->[H2O] $B$
\end{reaction}

\begin{reaction}
 SO4^2- + Ba^2+ -> BaSO4 v
\end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much. This will be very useful for everyone dealing with math and chemisty simultaneously

Answer (score 4):

To develop an environment `\begin{reaction}...\end{reaction}` you can use the code below:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mhchem}
\newenvironment{reaction}{\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}}
\newenvironment{reaction*}{\begin{equation*}}{\end{equation*}}
\begin{document}
\begin{reaction}
 \ce{$A$ ->[\ce{+H2O}] $B$}
\end{reaction}
\begin{reaction}
\ce{SO4^2- + Ba^2+ -> BaSO4 v}
 \end{reaction}
\end{document}
```

To develop a `listofreactions` use the `titletoc` package.

Comment: This however does use the same counter as equation.

Answer (score 4):

This is my solution now including a separate reaction counter and a new list of reactions. It is not fully tested yet but works in my simple test document

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mhchem}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\newcommand{\reactionlistname}{List of reactions}
\newlistof{reactions}{rxs}{\reactionlistname}

\newcounter{reaction}
\newcounter{tmp}
\newenvironment{reaction}[1][\relax]{%
\setcounter{tmp}{\value{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{\value{reaction}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}
\begin{equation}
\addcontentsline{rxs}{reactions}{\protect\numberline{\thereaction}#1}
}{%
\end{equation}
\setcounter{reaction}{\value{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{\value{tmp}}
}


\begin{document}


\listofreactions

\begin{reaction}[bla]
 \ce{$A$ ->[\ce{+H2O}] $B$}
\end{reaction}

\begin{reaction}
\ce{SO4^2- + Ba^2+ -> BaSO4 v}
 \end{reaction}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @cgnieder it is possible to use chemmacros package.

My solution involves the change of the reference brackets and the introduction of an additional letter to denote them.

Please, note that `\usepackage{chemmacros}` is essential not to get an error.

```latex
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\usechemmodule{reactions}

\chemsetup[reactions]{
  before-tag = R ,
  tag-open = ( ,
  tag-close = )
}

\begin{document}

\listofreactions

\begin{reactions}
    CH4 + H2O <=> CO + 3 H2
\end{reactions}

\end{document}
```

If you have more than one reaction, you can align them with respect to a specific point, by adding `&`, and also refer to every equation, for example:

```latex
\begin{reactions}
    \label{her:Volmer}
    H3O+ + e- + $\ast$ &-> H$\ast$ + H2O \quad \text{(Volmer)} \\
    \label{her:Heyrovsky}
    H3O+ + H$\ast$ + e- &-> H2 + H2O \quad \text{(Heyrovsky)} \\
    \label{her:Tafel}
    2 H$\ast$ + e- &-> H2 \quad \text{(Tafel)}
\end{reactions}
```

[image: Output]

Comment: You should also add `\chemsetup{formula=mhchem}` otherwise `chemmacros` won't use `mhchem`