# Create New Type of Align Environment with Unique Counter

Tags: equations, align, mhchem

I am trying to typeset some chemical equations in my thesis, and I would like to have the chemical equations have a unique counter from regular equations.

I also need to have some of them align over the -> . I know I can use \cee{} from the mhchem package within the align environment, but I don't know to separate the counters.

I tried fiddling with creating a new environment, but couldn't get it to work right at all (first time trying that out...). I would love to have an aligned environment "chemical" that did all this.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What did you try? How didn't it work?

Comment: Well, I tried something like this:

`\newenvironment{chemical}%
 {\renewcommand{\theequation}{\thereaction}%
 \begin{align}}%
 {\end{align} \renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{equation}}}`

where \thereaction is related to a custom "reaction" counter. But I couldn't figure out how to force the align environment to temporarily increment the reaction counter instead of the equation counter, so I was stuck.

Comment: Have you tried the [`chemmacros`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chemmacros) package?

Comment: @Jellby I just looked through the documentation (rather quickly, admittedly)for `chemmacros`, but it appears to be a different implementation of what mhchem is doing. Really what I would like to know is how to temporarily redirect `align` to utilize a different counter than `equation`.

I managed to use {align*} and manually input a custom tag command on each equation. It works, but just seemed a little inelegant (having to remember to do this manually every time).

Comment: I was referring specifically to the `reactions` environment, which gives you the alignment and the separate numbering.

Comment: You can use `\usepackage[method=mhchem]{chemmacros}` and ignore its formula building macros (i.e., the complete part III of the manual). You can then still use `chemmacros`'s reaction environments (section 12 of the manual).

Comment: Well great. As soon as I go and do it the hard way I come back to see great replies. Well, I guess I learned something at least. Thanks for your responses! I'll check them out as well.

Comment: See also the [other question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11456/number-mhchem-reactions-and-create-a-listofreactions) about numbering `mhchem` reactions...

Comment: @cgneider Thanks for the pointer, I don't know if I'll end up having to do a LoE like that, but it's good to know how.

Answer (score 2):

So, I figured out how to get what I wanted working by creating a new environment (modeled on the subequations implementation). I additionally created a "subreaction" environment as well.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\newcounter{reaction}
\renewcommand\thereaction{C\,\thechapter.\arabic{reaction}}

\renewcommand{\thereaction}{C\,\thechapter.\arabic{reaction}}
\newcommand{\thealignedreaction}{C\,\thechapter.\arabic{equation}}

\makeatletter
\newenvironment{reactionalign}{%
    \mathchardef\c@mainequation\c@equation
    \protected@edef\themainequation{\theequation}%
    \let\theequation\thealignedreaction
    \global\c@equation\c@reaction
    }%
    {
    \global\c@equation\c@mainequation
    \global\@ignoretrue
    }
\makeatother


\newcommand{\thesubreaction}{\themainreaction\alph{equation}}

\makeatletter   
\newenvironment{subreactions}{%
    \refstepcounter{reaction}%
    \mathchardef\c@mainequation\c@equation
    \protected@edef\themainequation{\theequation}%
    \mathchardef\c@mainreaction\c@reaction
    \protected@edef\themainreaction{\thereaction}%
    \let\theequation\thesubreaction
    \global\c@equation\z@
    }{%
    \global\c@reaction\c@mainreaction
    \global\c@equation\c@mainequation
    \global\@ignoretrue
    }
\makeatother

%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\chapter{Example}
\begin{equation}
    A = B
\end{equation}

\begin{subreactions}
    \begin{align}
        \cee{2H2 + O2 &-> 2H2O}\\
        \cee{CH4 + 2O2 &-> 2H2O + CO2}
    \end{align}
\end{subreactions}

\begin{reactionalign}
    \begin{align}
        \cee{H2O2 + H2 &-> 3H2O}\\
        \cee{2C2H6 + 7O2 -> 4CO2 + 6H2O}
    \end{align}
\end{reactionalign}

\begin{equation}
    C = D
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

This works perfectly, preserving the correct last value of the equation counter, while working well with the reaction counter too.

Sorry for the wall-o-code. I couldn't figure out how to post a MWE (new to the forum).

I hope this helps people. And if someone can find a better way to implement this, let me know!

EDIT: This is the hard way to go about this. See comments above for more efficient options.